# Dynamic bigquery query in dataflow template

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've written a Dataflow job that works great when I run it manually. Here is the relevant section (with some validation code removed for clarity):

```
parser.add_argument('--end_datetime',
                    dest='end_datetime')
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

query = <redacted SQL String with a placeholder for a date>
query = query.replace('#ENDDATETIME#', known_args.end_datetime)

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    rows = p | 'read query' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True))
```

Now I want to create a template and schedule it to run on a regular basis with a dynamic ENDDATETIME. As I understand it, in order to do this I need to change add_argument to add_value_provider_argument per this documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates

Unfortunately, it appears that ValueProvider values are not available when I need them, they're only available inside the pipeline itself. (please correct me if I'm wrong here...). So I'm kind of stuck.

Does anyone have any pointers on how I could get a dynamic date into my query in a Dataflow template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python currently only supports ValueProvider options for FileBasedSource IOs. You can see that by clicking on the Python tab at the link you used:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates

under the "Pipeline I/O and runtime parameters" section.

Comment: Yes, but ValueProvider works in other, non IO methods. For example the "Using ValueProvider in your functions" example on that page uses ValueProvider values in a ParDo. So one way to solve this would be to modify the query variable in a DoFn, but I don't see a way to get that modified variable back to the main program in a way that can be used in subsequent pipeline steps.

Comment: Unlike what happens in Java, BigQuery in Python does not use a custom source. In other words, it is not fully implemented in the SDK but also contains parts in the backend. Currently, only native (not custom sources) can use templates. There are plans to have BigQuery added as custom.

Comment: I mean only custom sources can use templates. (The rest is correct). I meant to specify that "native" is the opposite of "custom," so native sources can't use templates (the current case for Python BigQuery). Here is the plan to have BigQuery added as a custom source: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1440

Comment: Very useful to know. Thanks!

Comment: hi there! @MaríaGarcíaHerrero any update on this? As the original question, I need templated arguments to format a BigQuery query using the Python SDK

Comment: @garcianavalon: There are currently no estimated date on when that will be added to the Python SDK, as we are currently busy with releasing Python streaming features :)

Comment: @MaríaGarcíaHerrero thanks for your answer :) Is this feature easy to contribute to for? (is designed and agreeded upon, just coding needed) It will simplify some of our pipelines and I will gladly contribute to it